# xml data is not retreiving

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Hello everyone i am trying to retrieve the XML data in repeater with C#. But it is giving me error 
Here is my code

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Data/comments.xml"));
    var result = doc.Descendants("comments").Where(x => x.Element("postid").Value == Request.QueryString["id"] && x.Element("status").Value == "Y").Select(x => new
    {


         id=x.Element("id").Value,
        name = x.Element("name").Value,
        comment = x.Element("Comment").Value,
         commenttime = x.Element("Commenttime").Value
        //status=x.Element("status").Value
    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Take(1);
    Repeater2.DataSource = result;
    Repeater2.DataBind();
}
```

Here is my xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tbcomments>
  <comments>
    <id>1</id>
    <postid>4</postid>
    <name>azad</name>
    <emailid>chouhan.azad99@gmail.com</emailid>
    <Comment>nice flower</Comment>
    <CommentTime>6/22/2013 2:43:49 PM</CommentTime>
    <status>Y</status>
  </comments>
  <comments>
</tbcomments>
```

It is giving me error this 
[image]

please tell me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML element names are case sensitive. You have CommentTime in your source XML, but Commenttime in your code. I would also suggest using string casts instead of `.Value` to avoid NullReferenceExceptions:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Data/comments.xml"));
var result = doc.Descendants("comments")
                .Where(x => x.Element("postid").Value == 
                            Request.QueryString["id"] && 
                            x.Element("status").Value == "Y")
                .Select(x => new
{
    id= (string)x.Element("id"),
    name = (string)x.Element("name"),
    comment = (string)x.Element("Comment"),
    commenttime = (string)x.Element("CommentTime")
    //status=x.Element("status").Value
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Take(1);
Repeater2.DataSource = result;
Repeater2.DataBind();
```

Comment: such a little mistake i did not find how stupid i am.. :( by the way thanks it work now

Answer (score 0):

Current problem: "Commenttime" is spelled wrong (should be "CommentTime").

Other problems:

- non standard naming for class members in public samples. Use UpperCase for public property/field names.
- inconsistent naming of nodes (some uppercase, some lower case).
- non-DRY code: `x.Element(someName).Value` repeated several times inline and hence lasking any null checks.
- not simplifying problem sample enough before posting